# Svelte - usage of Context API (setContext/getContext) over regular props passing

Tags: javascript, svelte

Here is a simple example:

```
<script>
    import Button from './Button.svelte';

    let text = 'Click me!';
    let sayHello = () => alert('Hello!');
</script>

<Button {text} {sayHello}/>
<Button {text} {sayHello}/>
<Button {text} {sayHello}/>
```

And if I get it right, since there can be lots of `<Button {text} {sayHello}/>`, it'll be nice to omit props passing somehow

And here comes **Context API**:

```
<script>
    import Button from './Button.svelte';
    import { setContext } from 'svelte';
    import { text, sayHello } from './data.js';

    setContext(text, 'Click me!');
    setContext(sayHello, () => alert('Hello!'));
</script>

<Button/>
<Button/>
<Button/>
```

*And somewhere in `./Button.svelte` there are `getContext()` usage, etc*

---

So, is the ability to omit similar props passing is the only reason to use Svelte's **Context API**?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> So, is the ability to omit similar props passing is the only reason to use Svelte's Context API?

No, and, in my opinion, it is even not a very good usage of context.

The problem here is that you're obfuscating the data relationship between your parent component and its button children.

With props, it is explicit what data is needed by the button and where it comes from. On the other hand, with context, you only see one side of the relationship at once. In the parent, you don't see how the data is used (or even if it is still used at all). Same in the child, you don't see where it comes from.

Also, mistyping a prop, or removing one that is still needed for example, will result in an instantly visible dev warning (replete with the exact location of the problem). With context, you might end up with an undefined value that will produce weird runtime behaviour but will be hard to track down.

So, while saving a little bit of typing might seem like a good idea when you're in the process of coding and have everything fresh in your head, it actually increases the complexity of your code and might play tricks on you and give you a big headache later down the road... Not a good trade off if you want my opinion.

There are situations, however, where props are not an option. That is, when the data consumer component is not a direct child of the data provider component.

For example, you might have some kind of user session in your app. It will most likely be stored in a component near the root of your components tree (say, App), but it will be needed in components several levels of nesting deeper. For example, in a component displaying the user's name. Or somewhere else in a page, displaying some parts based on whether the user is authenticated or not.

You could pass by props through every components down the line, but this is kind of insane. This would tie all the intermediate components to data they're absolutely not concerned with.

So, in a case like this, context makes full sense. You would `setContext` in the `App` component, and can access it from just the components that need it.

Another example would be some kind of "composite" component, where you have a wrapping component (for example a form) and multiple components that can be used inside of it (for example inputs) and that depends on some settings in the container.

```html
<Form>
  <Input />
</Form>
```

Here, the `Form` component can't pass props to the `Input` component because the `Input` is not created directly in the `Form` component. It is fed to it by mean of a slot, and the `Form` can't see the content of this slot.

Still, `Input` is nested under `Form` in the resulting component tree, and so you can pass data between them through context.

To sum it up, context is really meant for situations where you can't use props. Either because it would be impracticable and lead to bad architecture, or because it is technically impossible (slots).

As an alternative to context, you could store the data in a dedicated JS module that both the provider and the consumer would access (e.g. `import { setData, getData } from './data-source.js'`) BUT that would make your components singletons. This data could only be global. With context, on the other hand, you could have as many isolated data "scopes" as you need, one for each instance of the data provider component. In the `Form` example above, multiple `<Form>` components could coexist in your app at the same time, each having their own data in context. (They could even be nested inside each other and it would work.)

To conclude, here's a piece of advice. Context in Svelte is implemented with JS `Map` object, so you don't have to use raw strings as context keys. I generally use plain objects (or Symbol if you want to be fancy) that I export from something like a `constants.js` module. This largely mitigates the mistyping and IDE confusion issues I mentioned earlier.

`constants.js`

```js
export const key = {name: 'my-context'}
```

`Form.svelte`

```html
<script>
  import { setContext } from 'svelte'
  import { key } from './constants.js'

  setContext(key, { ... })
</script>

<slot />
```

`Input.svelte`

```html
<script>
  import { getContext } from 'svelte'
  import { key } from './constants.js'

  const { ... } = getContext(key)
</script>

...
```

This eliminates any risk of context key collision you could have with a raw string. It turns mistyping back into a fail fast and crash noisily error (which is good). And it gives your IDE a far better clue as to what is happening in your code (an ES import can easily be parsed by dev tools, while strings are just random blobs to them), allowing it be far more helpful to you when you'll need to refactor that...

Comment: Rixo: I thank you for your detailed answer because I'm struggling to understand how to organize a button component clicked and pass props to it. Your answer cleared a lot of confusion. I appreciate it if you take a look and guide me to best practices as I'm focusing my time on svelte/sapper .    If you care, here is my question link:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62224782/svelte-way-for-obtaining-props-values-in-parent-component-and-passing-to-a-chil

Comment: Thanks for this thorough answer! *"the Form component can't pass props to the Input component because the Input is not created directly in the Form component" / "...or because it is technically impossible (slots)."* There's a way to do this, the props could be passed to the slot via the `let:directive` in this case https://svelte.dev/tutorial/slot-props